# Доступ к переменной внутри функции для отображения ее значения в message для модуля/метода logdecorator.async_log_on_end

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как можно в сообщении (message) для `logdecorator.async_log_on_end` отобразить значение локальной переменной функции к которой применятся декоратор?
Для нижен приведенного примера нужно отобразить значение var2 по завершению работы функции f

```
import asyncio
import logging
from logdecorator.asyncio import async_log_on_end, async_log_on_start
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


class Test:
    @async_log_on_start(logging.INFO, "Start {var1}")
    @async_log_on_end(logging.INFO, "End {var2}")
    async def f(self, var1):
        var2 = var1 + 100
        return 'Hello world!'


async def main():
    test = Test()

    await test.f(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    lock = asyncio.Lock()
    myState = 0
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(main())
    loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Просто через logging выведите внутри самой функции. logdecorator логирует только то что входит, выходит и ошибки.

Comment: Да так делаю, но не нравится такой вариант. Код становится не красивым.

Comment: Есть воркаарунд. Входной параметер может быть структурой. В саму эту структуру добавлять нужный параметр для отображения. А далее в message обращаться к структуре по новому ключу. Но опять таки это кривое решение.